# How to display data into GridView after click a button

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Hi I have two gridView and one button. When I press the button, it will process the data on gridView1. Here is the code of the button process :

```
 Protected Sub btnHitung_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHitung.Click
    Dim vNhari As String = ddlNhari.SelectedValue

    'Jika belum pilih jumlah hari
    If vNhari = "" Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "Validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Pilih hari terlebih dahulu')</script>")
    Else
        'Get batas min. tanggal dari jumlah hari yang dipilih
        Dim vLtgl As Date = Date.Now.AddDays(-vNhari).ToShortDateString
        For Nhari As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(vNhari)
            Dim jumSaham As Int32
            Dim jum As Int32
            For data As Integer = 0 To InvestorGridView.Rows.Count - 1      '-1 : Untuk exclude header
                'Jika tanggal pada dataGrid = vLtgl, maka ambil datanya
                If Convert.ToDateTime(InvestorGridView.Rows(data).Cells(0).Text).ToShortDateString = vLtgl Then
                    jum = Convert.ToInt32(InvestorGridView.Rows(data).Cells(3).Text)
                End If
                jumSaham = jumSaham + jum
            Next
            vLtgl = vLtgl.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyone know how can I store the vLtgl value and jumSaham value into a datatable and then show it in gridView2? I really stuck here.
Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use a datatable, just update the cells in the second table to vLtgl and jumSaham

Comment: Hi Chuck, can you please give me the example code? Thanks

Comment: Something like this: gridView2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(0).Text = vLtgl.Tostring and gridView2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Text = jumSaham.Tostring